# SQL: Is selecting Substring of TEXT field faster than whole value

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have [TEXT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-text/) data type (up to 65,535 characters), is taking first 500 characters faster than the whole column? There is a LEFT function that can particularly be used in this situation, but I'm wondering if it improves performance or maybe downgrades it, since it is a function after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InnoDB storage engine has to read the full TEXT content regardless. The `LEFT()` function operates on the full string. It doesn't have any way of telling the storage engine to read only part of the string.

In an RDBMS where functions had intimate knowledge of the storage format, string functions like `LEFT()` could be optimized in clever ways.

But MySQL has a distinct plugin architecture to implement ar variety of storage engines. The storage code is separate from storage-independent things like builtin string functions. So a string function has no opportunity to request part of a TEXT column.

The code that implements MySQL's `LEFT()` function is here: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/item_strfunc.cc#L1443-L1461

The only optimization is that it checks the length of the string. If the string is already shorter than the requested substring, it just returns the whole string. This implies that the full string must be available to check the length.

Comment: Thank you. I did presume that it would have to “load” the whole data prior to only returning the LEFT amount of characters, but wanted to make sure

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Bill Karwin's answer..

You can easily check that with the `BENCHMARK()` function, which shows that there is no difference.

```
SET @a:= repeat(uuid(), 65535 / 32);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,001 sec)

SELECT BENCHMARK(10000000, LEFT(@a,500));
1 row in set (16,017 sec)

SELECT BENCHMARK(10000000, @a);
1 row in set (16,031 sec)
```

If you do a SELECT with LEFT() it will be of course much faster, since network traffic (but also memory usage) is much smaller.

Comment: So while it will make no different to database, it might benefit the application let’s say, since we will less data in memory and thus let’s sat HTTP call will be faster? Is this a good way to think about it?

Comment: Or could a performance of db also be better, not from speed standpoint, rather on load. Let’s say db is getting hammered with requests, loading less could help?

Comment: It improves also the speed of the server, since less memory needs to be copied into network buffer, and less data has to be sent over the wire.